# SPARQL for unique set of values from all columns and rows

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a query that returns several columns, i.e.:

```
SELECT ?a ?b ?c
WHERE { ... }
```

Every column variable is an IRI. Obviously this returns a unique row for every combination of column values (note that values may not be unique to a column):

```
<urn:id:x:1> <urn:id:a:2> <urn:id:j:3>
<urn:id:x:1> <urn:id:a:2> <urn:id:j:4>
<urn:id:x:1> <urn:id:j:4> <urn:id:k:5>
<urn:id:y:2> <urn:id:j:4> <urn:id:k:6>
...
```

However, all I need are the unique IRIs spanning all rows and columns. i.e.:

```
<urn:id:x:1>
<urn:id:a:2>
<urn:id:j:3>
<urn:id:j:4>
<urn:id:k:5>
<urn:id:y:2>
<urn:id:k:6>
...
```

Is it possible to achieve this using SPARQL, or do I need to post-process the results to merge and de-deduplicate the values? Order is unimportant.

Comment: the most simple but clearly most expensive (depending on the query optimizer) way would be to wrap the graph pattern in subqueries per each column and use the `UNION` of those. Something like `SELECT DISTINCT ?x { {select ?x { ?x ?p ?o } } UNION {select ?x { ?s ?x ?o } } UNION  { select ?x {?s ?p ?x }}  }` - well I think you get the idea? And as I said, might have poor performance and there might be other ways - was just the first and most trivial option that came into my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?d {
    ...
    VALUES ?i { 1 2 3 }
    BIND (if(?i=1, ?a, if(?i=2, ?b, ?c)) AS ?d)
}
```

What does this do?

1. The `VALUES` clause creates three copies of each solution and numbers them with a variable `?i`
2. The `BIND` clause creates a new variable `?d` whose value is `?a`, `?b` or `?c`, depending on whether `?i` is 1, 2 or 3 in the given solution
3. The `SELECT DISTINCT ?d` returns only `?d` and removes duplicates

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the semantics of this. You can only assign a variable to be a sequence of arbitrary values through `VALUES`, but variables are invalid within `VALUES`, so the only way to generate a sequence from variables is through a 2-step join via `BIND` using an `IF` expression like this?

Comment: Correct. At least it’s the only way I could think of that doesn’t involve triplicating the whole query pattern.